# How can I pass Gitlab token stored on Jenkins to pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I'm a Jenkins user. Jenkins server has a Gitlab token. How can I pass this token to a pipeline script (Jenkinsfile) so I can use Gitlab API v4.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the Jenkinsfile? Can you edit your question with some snippet of your code?

Comment: Agree with Nico above. We need more information. But if you're referring to the API token that you put in the GitLab plugin settings in global Jenkins settings, you cannot access that/use that directly in your Jenkins jobs. You would have to copy that token or use another one directly in your script.